# CartoDB Torque not showing year in slider

Tags: carto, torque

I'm trying to set up a map using Torque with CartoDB's in browser wizard.  I've set the time column to year, but the this does not show up on the slider.  Anyone know how to make year display in the slider rather than a count/ID number?

This is my test map:
https://jamaps.cartodb.com/viz/e956c248-5cd0-11e5-ae08-0e6e1df11cbf/public_map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your viz.json, it seems that your map is set up with -torque-time-attribute:"year".

There's a known issue/behaviour in Torque: by using a numeric column as your year column, it will start with a count.

Make sure your date column is of type "date" and it will work as expected!

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there is a way to batch convert years (stored as numbers) to the date format in CartoDB?  Or can this only be done manually or in an external environment and then re-imported?

Comment: You can just change the type of the column in CartoDB, clicking in the column name and changing the type to date. It will interpret numbers as years directly! You can make a copy of the table first to make sure your data doesn't get nulled or something in case you are doing weird casts, but I always do this trick and always works :-)